# fixed header and footer with scroll-able content+ unclickable hyper link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, frontend, css-position

I'm having this problem that my header,footer and bar part are not fixed when i scroll through the page if i attach an image the image kinda off overlaps and becomes above the header.
this is the css code:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.header{
   height: 80px;
 width: 100%;
    background: url(images/header.jpeg);
    position: fixed;
}
.bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 43px;
    background: url(images/menu-boarder.jpeg);
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
}
body{
     margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 80%;
}
.menu{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
.menu li{
    display: inline-block;

}
.menu li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;

}
.menu li a:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    padding: 43px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  right:80px;


}

.searchTerm {
  width: 400%;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 20px;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #000000;
}

.homeage_product {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}


.homeage_but {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.searchButton {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #000000;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.fa-shopping-cart, .glyphicon-user{

    color: #000000;

}
#lblCartCount {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.form-inline {
   display: flex;

}


.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(images/footer.jpeg);
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

the html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Cookie|Bakery shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
        </div>
    <br><br><br><br>
 <div class="bar">
        <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
        </ul>



      <div class="search">
         <form class="form-inline">
              <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
              <button type="submit" class="searchButton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 
            </form>
```

also here i can't figure out  why the following  `<div>` tag is not clickable (meaning the user and the shooping cart):

```
<div class="icons">
 <a herf="xx.html"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="font-size:36px; margin-right: 10px;">
      <asp:Label ID="lblCartCount" ForeColor="White"/>3</i></a>
 <a herf=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size:30px; margin-right: 5px; "></i></a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

the rest of the html code:

```
       </div>
    <div class="content">
    <!-- Image of a product with button refrence to the product it self  -->
<div class="homeage_product" >
  <img src="images/cake.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%; height:300px; padding: 0;">

    <button class="homeage_but" >CLICK ME!</button>

</div>
        </div>

        <h4><center><u>Welome to our Bakery shop!</u></center></h4>
        <p>
           Lorem ipnam dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Sed felis turpis, ulturicies nee herndrerit a
          ullarneorper in maars Donee a erat molestie, condimentum ex eu, vehicula elst Ut egestas consectenor
          libero, et dictum elir tineidunt sed Sed tellus nisi, faciliais sut nulla eu, euismod blandit marpia. Praesent
          uficies semper auctor. Quisque eftieitur sollacstudin metus pec porta. Donec bbero notla, accumsan ut
          negue sit amet, tincsdurt facilisis felis. Phasellus ac ante pretium, vehicula ex sed, feugsat ipsum Nullam
          dapibus erat vitae ligula venenatis vestibulum Morbi aliquam sapien eu volutpet volutpat. Quisquue
          sapien nisl, pulvinar eu finabua eget, tempus quis ante Cras sed blandst eros. Quisque posuere eros at
          tellus tincidtant tristique.

        </p>
        <div  class="footer">


        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index your header style in css:

```
.header
{
    z-index: 99;
}
```

The z-index property specifies the overlay order of positioned elements. Elements with a greater z-index will therefore always be in front of elements with a lower z-index. Setting the z-index to a value greater than (or even equal to) 0 sets that element to be on top of non-positioned elements with no z-index specified. You could always set it to a value lower than 99, but, it is common practice to avoid potential clashes with other positioned elements.

Let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: yes it did work!!!! as for the the non-clickable did you know where is my fault part  :(???

Comment: it worked for the image part but the <p> tag is still not showing all the way and the scrolling capability is not there for me to see the <p> tag and scroll through it

Comment: please if you have time checkout my latest questions it has all my questions there!

Comment: So it works :) Can you please correct my answer and I will help you in your next question